# Too many values when using each_with_index iterator in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a result set (`Mongoid::Criteria`) in Ruby that is the result of a `mongoid` query. While adding some formatting to the output of my iteration over this result set, I am sometimes getting extras.

For example:

```
widgets = Things.where(type: 'widget')
```

Says that the count of widgets is 20, if I do:

```
widgets.each_with_index do |sprocket, index|
  puts "#{sprocket.name} is number #{index} in the list." 
  ...lots of code...
  yield sprocket
end
```

I will get 22 lines back, with two of the 20 sprockets in widgets being duplicated. This loop is inside a larger loop. When I rerun my code it does not happen every time, nor does it repeat the same sprockets each time.

What is odd is that if do:

```
widgets.each do |sprocket, index|
  puts "#{sprocket.name} is number #{index} in the list."
end
```

I get a list of 20 items.

I have gone through my data and can't find a pattern that explains this behavior.

Why does `_each_with_index_` sometimes returns more items?

Comment: What's happening in `...lots of code...`? Are you sure that that code isn't causing this behavior?